# Apk for only one device/user

Tags: android, ios, apk, ipa

I want to create an apk for only one devices. I have to send an apk to my client. I want to send him the apk for only one device **as we do in IOS using UUID(device id).** it is an enterprise level app. He don't need to upload it , he may just make copy of it and use it in his office.

How could i solve this issue?

Is there any way.

**As we create some software which can run on particular computer who have paid and other have to pay before using these software.**

We also do this thing in IOS in which `we take device id of user and create an ipa only for that user`.

Comment: Why dont you make a login screen and share the credentials only to the authorized user ?

Comment: then i definetly need website and he may login with the authorized user from each device,

Comment: Keep the credentials offline. Use encryption before you save the credentials locally. Though I m not sure of your exact use case!

Comment: You can achieve this by using ***Device ID***. You can't avoid installation process of app but you can restrict user to use app. In application class/in launcher activity compare client's device id, if matched the move ahead else exit app.  To restrict app to upload on playstore give apk with debug certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Bind it with the IMEI of the device.

Just check the IMEI of the device running your app with the provided IMEI and open your activity only if the IMEI is correct.

Comment: IMEI is not good for Android, some device didn't are phones)

I recommend you to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id for more about nique id on Android. THe answer on the bottom (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17625641/1377145) is quite completed.